# How can I make this API work with a payload?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I am using this API to list users. One of the parameters I could specify is a team id which is placed in an array. When I try to specify a team id it doesn't work when I put it in the payload, but it works when I change the url to include the team id.

This is the API reference: https://api-reference.pagerduty.com/#!/Users/get_users

Here is what I am basing my code off of: https://github.com/PagerDuty/API_Python_Examples/blob/master/REST_API_v2/Users/list_users.py

This is my code when I try to specify team id in the payload. It doesn't work like this for some reason, but it works when I change the url to `url = 'https://api.pagerduty.com/users?team_ids%5B%5D=TEAMID&team_ids%5B%5D='` where in TEAMID I have an actual team id.

```
with open('config/config.json') as f:
    config = json.load(f)

API_KEY = config['API_KEY']
TEAM_IDS = ['TEAMID']

def list_users():

    url = 'https://api.pagerduty.com/users'
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2',
        'Authorization': 'Token token={token}'.format(token=API_KEY)
    }
    payload = {
        'team_ids[]': TEAM_IDS
    }
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    result = []
    if r.status_code == 200:
        # loops for each user and retrieves their email
        result = [user['email'] for user in r.json()['users']]
        return result
    else:
        return None
```

I want to get this work by listing team id's in the array and sending it in the payload so that I can list more than one team id and not clutter them all in the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need something like this

```
payload = {
    'team_ids[]': TEAM_IDS 
}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't believe I missed that. :)

Comment: no prob, if that helped, feel free to upvote/accept the answer to close the question